# mostrar a partir de la proxima posición un dato de la BD

Tags: python, django

necesito ayuda ya que no logro mostrar la información como quiero.

Estoy generando la siguiente lista de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que en el caso de `Consumo Madrugada` en ves de comenzar por la 1ra posición (que esta mostrando 0) comience a mostrar a partir de la 2da posición (que es 42).

Adjunto el codigo del `Html`, donde imagino que la respuesta estaria en el `for`

```
{% for c in object_list %} 
        <tr>    
            <td>{{ c.pgd }}</td>
            <td>{{ c.fecha | date:"d-m-Y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ c.lec_madrugada }}</td>
            <td>{{ c.cons_madrugada }}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

si puedes evitar que se muestre la primer iteración:

```
{% for c in object_list %} 
    {% if not forloop.first %}
    <tr>    
        <td>{{ c.pgd }}</td>
        <td>{{ c.fecha | date:"d-m-Y" }}</td>
        <td>{{ c.lec_madrugada }}</td>
        <td>{{ c.cons_madrugada }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Espero que sea la solución a tu problema. Fijate en la documentación que forloop tiene varias propiedades más. Es bastante interesante.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! pero el problema es que de esta forma no muestra todos los datos de la primera iteracion, y yo necesito que solo no muestre el de `c.lec_madrugada`

Comment: Y usas if forloop.first y pones lo que quieras poner y en el else pones todo ese código que te propuse

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if forloop.first %}
<tr>    
    <td>{{ c.pgd }}</td>
    <td>{{ c.fecha | date:"d-m-Y" }}</td>
    <td>NO QUIERO PONER NADA</td>
    <td>TAMPOCO QUIERO PONER NADA</td>
</tr>
{% else %}
<tr>    
    <td>{{ c.pgd }}</td>
    <td>{{ c.fecha | date:"d-m-Y" }}</td>
    <td>{{ c.lec_madrugada }}</td>
    <td>{{ c.cons_madrugada }}</td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```